# Should "the" be used in this sentence?

Tags: grammatical-number, definite-articles

> To make right decisions, see the big picture first.

In this sentence (slogan), do you need to place "the" before the word "right"? We're having a discussion here and some people think that you don't need it, because it's a plural and/or not a very "definite" thing ("right decisions").

(Also, is the comma correctly placed and are there other mistakes?)

Comment: I'd far prefer the inclusion of the definite article here. This then balances context: the big picture (relevant to the discussion and not necessarily life, the universe and everything) as compared with the right decisions (relevant to the subject being discussed, or, as here, implied). I'd not include 'the' in 'To make right / correct decisions, you need to get a decent amount of sleep'. Here, the decisions are totally unspecified. // This really goes beyond grammatical acceptability, which many believe is the only constraint.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Oxford Online Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/the?q=the+), *the* is used for:

> Denoting one or more people or things already mentioned or assumed to
>   be common knowledge:

Whether those decisions (you will make in the future) are right or wrong could be judged based on the decisions that you made in the past. In such case, ***the right decisions*** seems to be the correct one as you would know what kind of decision is right or wrong. You are using *the* before *big picture* for the same reason.

There are more cases where *the* is used before such adjectives as *right* or *wrong*. The below Ngram Viewer seems to show it.

[image]